# Can't run Ubuntu from disc

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, boot, livecd, optical-drive

When I place the boot CD in my CD drive and boot from it, I get the Ubuntu menu.

I have these options

- Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer
- Install Ubuntu
- Check disc for defects
- Test memory
- Boot from first hard disk

I can use the cursor keys to select them, and I can push F1 for help etc.

However, I can not *select* an option. I've highlighted the first and tried enter, space bar etc.

I do have a KVM, so I plugged in a 2nd USB keyboard and tried it but no go either.

I can push escape and then got to the prompt.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: do you have a ps/2 keyboard to try?  if not, do you have a bios setting for "usb legacy" support?  this sounds like a bios-can't-use-usb-keyboard issue, which "usb legacy" should fix.

Comment: @quack I'll have a look. Does it sound weird to you though that other keys work?

Comment: a little, yeah; i'd expect the bios-can't-use-usb-keyboard problem to show as *no* keys work, but it's worth checking to make sure.  afaik there's no usb driver in livecd bootloader (isolinux/syslinux) so it should all be up to the bios.

Comment: Actually I think the enter key does work, but it is hanging because it can't read the disc correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try burning a new Ubuntu disc. That should do it. Otherwise, you may need a new CD drive.